# To copy the buffered zip file contents to remote machine

Tags: node.js

I am getting the browsed zip file as buffered hexadecimal contents.
How can i copy the zipped file to my remote machine

Answer (score 1):

You can use this, https://github.com/cthackers/adm-zip

```
    // creating archives
    var zip = new AdmZip();

    // add file directly
    zip.addFile("test.txt", new Buffer("inner content of the file"), "entry comment goes here");
    // add local file
    zip.addLocalFile("/home/me/some_picture.png");
    // get everything as a buffer
    var willSendthis = zip.toBuffer();
    // or write everything to disk
    zip.writeZip(/*target file name*/"/home/me/files.zip");
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply Raheem. Can i get the absolute path name of the file browsed????

Comment: The think the code you have shared is to create a zip file, but i have a zip file already ,which is in hexadecimal

Comment: fs.realpathSync('files.zip', []);